# Google Spreadsheet =Filter in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have this formula in google spreadsheet that uses the =FILTER functionality but I can't seem to find the corresponding syntax in excel. Specifically the formula is as follows:

=FILTER(A2:C6,B2:B6=2)

What this does is look at column B for the the value "2" and displays all the information from column A to C with that value.

Any ideas on how to put this functionality in excel?

Comment: Unfortunately such a formula doesn't exist in excel up to version 2010, you can do it with combination of other formulas, see a tutorial e.g. here: http://www.exceltactics.com/make-filtered-list-sub-arrays-excel-using-small/4/

Answer (score 0):

This would be pretty unwieldy for any more than three columns, but you can use multiple INDEX/MATCHEs to accomplish the same functionality.

```
=INDEX(A2:A7,MATCH(2,B2:B7,0))&2&INDEX(C2:C7,MATCH(2,B2:B7,0))
```

Returns the value from column A, then 2, then the value from column C, with nothing separating.